Does `call` opcode panic if less size data is returned?
I was reading the zksync documentation and found the following in the differences section here

For calls, you specify a memory slice to write the return data to,
e.g. out and outsize arguments for call(g, a, v, in, insize, out,
outsize). In EVM, if outsize != 0, the allocated memory will grow to
out + outsize (rounded up to the words) regardless of the
returndatasize. On zkSync Era, returndatacopy, similar to
calldatacopy, is implemented as a cycle iterating over return data
with a few additional checks and triggering a panic if out + outsize >
returndatasize to simulate the same behavior as in EVM.

What made me curious is why it says:

triggering a panic if out + outsize > returndatasize to simulate the
same behavior as in EVM.

To be honest, in EVM, if out + outsize > returndatasize, It doesn't panic. Looking into the solidity documentation about call opcode, we read:

If it returns less data, then the remaining bytes are not touched at
all

So it seems unclear to me why zksync says that they trigger a panic the same way EVM does. EVM doesn't do that. Then I got an answer from zksync team:

This is a typo in the documentation we have the same behavior as on
EVM. This is actually an interesting behavior on EVM side. If you do
returndatacopy will more data than returndatasize then it will panic,
but if you provide out/outsize in a call, it won't.

And I still don't understand what they mean.
